# Flutter: How to Split text into 2 lines

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I'm using columns to display 2 texts. 1st text represents the title and 2nd text displays the quotation. I'm trying to split the quotation text into multi-lines using the max line's property, but the text is overlapping with other items.  I try to use `Expanded` and flexible property to overcome this issue but still, I didn't get desired output. This is what I'm trying to do:

```
Container(
                      color: Color(0xff1D1D1D),
                      width: double.maxFinite,
                      height: responsivness.safeBlockVertical! * 54.55,
                      // Stories Title
                      child: Column(
                        children: [
                          Padding(
                            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                            child: Text("Stories",
                                style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline1!),
                          ),
                          // list of Stories
                          Expanded(
                            child: ListView.builder(
                              itemCount: 5,
                              shrinkWrap: true,
                              scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                                return Stack(
                                  clipBehavior: Clip.none,
                                  children: [
                                    Padding(
                                      padding: EdgeInsets.all(h * .014),
                                      child: Container(
                                        width:
                                            responsivness.safeBlockHorizontal! *
                                                47,
                                        height:
                                            responsivness.safeBlockVertical! *
                                                17,
                                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                          borderRadius:
                                              BorderRadius.circular(10),
                                          color: Colors.amber,
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                    Positioned(
                                      top: h * .19,
                                      left: h * .016,
                                      child: Column(
                                        mainAxisAlignment:
                                            MainAxisAlignment.start,
                                        crossAxisAlignment:
                                            CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                                        children: [
                                          Text(
                                            "Steve H.",
                                            style: Theme.of(context)
                                                .textTheme
                                                .headline1!,
                                          ),
                                          Text(
                                            "I bet away my house and all the money i got",
                                            style: Theme.of(context)
                                                .textTheme
                                                .bodyText2!,
                                            maxLines: 2,
                                            overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                                          ),
                                        ],
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                  ],
                                );
                              },
                            ),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
```

[image: This is what I'm getting as an output]

Answer (score 3):

Try below code hope its helpful to you. I think the problem comes from `Stack` widget so remove your `Stack` and `Positioned` **Widget**, and used `Column()` widget instead.

```
Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
      child: Column(
        children: [
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
            child: Text("Stories",
                style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline1!),
          ),
          // list of Stories
          Expanded(
            child: ListView.builder(
              itemCount: 5,
              shrinkWrap: true,
              scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                return Column(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                  children: [
                    Container(
                      width: 200,
                      height: 100,
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                        color: Colors.amber,
                      ),
                    ),
                    Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                      child: Column(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                        children: [
                          Text(
                            "Steve H.",
                          ),
                          Text(
                            "I bet away my house and all the money i got",
                            style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.bodyText2!,
                            maxLines: 2,
                            overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                );
              },
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    ),
```

Your result screen-> [image]

Answer (score 2):

Your text is overlapping because of the Stack widget. You can either wrap your text inside a sized box to give a fix width or you can remove `Stack` widget and use Column instead. I dont find any particular use of stack here, so probably you can remove it without any issues.

Comment: Agreed, removing `Stack` is a better solution.

Answer (score 2):

Try wrapping with container and specify any width

```
Container(
        width: 100,
        child: Text(
        "I bet away my house and all the money i got",
        style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.subtitle1,
        maxLines: 2,
        overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
        ),
),
```

Answer (score 0):

Try wrapping your overlapping `Text` with a fixed width `SizedBox`, and see if it fixes your issue.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried wrapping the Text in a FittedBox()

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31114483)